# Subclass uibutton .- changing title text reset frame to original size

Tags: uibutton, subclassing

I subclassed a uibutton and have some code that changes it's width/height. I have another function that just changes the title text. When I run that function, the button reverts back to its original size. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

enum ButtonType {
case newGameButton
case showStatsButton
case addTeamButton
case addUserButton
}

class LSS_Button: UIButton {

var myButtonType:ButtonType?
var originalHeight:CGFloat?


override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    if var titleFrame = self.titleLabel?.frame {
        titleFrame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height;
        titleFrame.origin.y = self.titleEdgeInsets.top + 3.0;

        self.titleLabel?.frame = titleFrame;
    }
}

func toggleSize() {

    var newFrame = self.frame
    var makeRound = false

    if self.frame.size.width != 40.0 {

        newFrame.size.width = 40.0
        newFrame.size.height = 40.0
        makeRound = true

    } else {

        if let newWidth = self.superview?.frame.size.width {
            newFrame.size.width = newWidth
            newFrame.size.height = self.originalHeight!
            makeRound = false
        }

    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {

        self.frame = newFrame

        if makeRound {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        } else {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
        }
    })
}

func editTitle(_ strTitle:String) {
    self.titleLabel?.text = strTitle
}
```

Here's some images of what happens:

[image: Original button]

[image: Changed size]

[image: After editing text]

Also, the button reverts back to the original text. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Been a while since I've coded iOS.

```
self.setTitle(strTitle, for: .normal)
```